# Change "more Info" in ArcGIS Online popup

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

I would like to change the text for the "more Info" popup which appears in my ArcGIS Online map next to my URL field. I would like it to say "Show image" or something more relevant than "more info".

Is there any way to change it?

Comment: You can either create a custom pop-up "custom attribute display" option and use the hyperlink tool in the editor, or if you dont mind the image being displayed in the pop-up you can use the "pop-up media option".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible if you are using the 'list of field attributes' option in the pop-up configuration. However if you use the 'custom attribute display' option you can modify the hyperlink text as shown in the image below.
[image]
Another possibility would be to use the 'pop-up media' option at the bottom of the pop-up configuration window.
[image]