# update “more Info” in ArcGIS Online WebMap popup

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

I am seeking to update the "more Info" text that appears for URLs in my AGOL WebMap popup. My query is a bit more complex than [Change “more Info” in ArcGIS Online popup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220878/change-more-info-in-arcgis-online-popup).

My dataset has a number of "Map" fields that contain links to various types of maps. I would like the name of map to appear in the for each URL instead of "More Info". I received the dataset as an excel with the name of each map displayed as a hyperlink to the map and this is how I would like it to be displayed in the popup (see image below).

[image: data smaple]

I don't think this is possible but I hope I am wrong!

Here is what currently is displayed:

[image: Current Popup]

This is what I want to be displayed:

[image: Required Popup]

Answer (score 2):

As a work around, I created "map title" fields for each "map link" field. The output can be seen below:

[image]